# assembly x8086 changing character color gone WRONG

Tags: assembly, x86

[**What the doctor told us to do:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzCm5.png)
it seems to me after trying to run it that when a vowel is being printed, it is printed 3 to 5 times I dont know why, and here is some screenshots of the output.
[**first output:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/levr4.png)
[**second output:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH1wE.png)
Can anyone help me here to understand what is wrong please?

```
org 100h 

.data

sentence db 100 dup(?),0dh   ;sentence with size 100 and an 'enter' to 
end it 
vowels db 'aeiouAEIOU'  ; vowels
colors db 04h, 0Bh, 0Dh, 0Ah,  0Eh 
;         red  cyan pink green yellow 

; add your code here
.code 
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax


; reading the input untill the user enters 'enter' 
; or untill it reachs 100 character
mov cx,100
mov si,0                                     

mov ah,1

input: 

int 21h

cmp al,0dh
jz endOfLine 

mov sentence[si],al
inc si

loop input 

jmp L1

; when the user inputs 'enter'
; it makes the next character of the sentence a 'enter'
; to make it as end of line refference

endOfLine:
mov sentence[si],0dh
                
                
; to centralize the output                    
L1:

mov dh, 12
mov dl, 30
mov bh, 0
mov ah, 2
int 10h 

; output part

mov si,0 

output:
mov dl,sentence[si]
 
cmp dl,0dh

jz stop_print

;checks for uppercase and lowercase vowel 
mov cx,5 
mov di,0

check_if_vowel:
 mov bl,vowels[di]

 cmp dl,bl
 jz is_vowel

 mov bl,vowels[di+5]
 cmp dl,bl

 jz is_vowel 
 inc di

loop check_if_vowel     

mov ah,2
int 21h 
inc si
jmp output

      
is_vowel: 
mov al,bl       
mov ah,09h
mov bl,colors[di]
int 10h 
  

mov ah,2      
mov dl,al
int 21h  


mov ah,09h
mov bh,0 
mov bl,0Fh
int 10h 


inc si
jmp output

stop_print:
ret
```

for me its seems correct as a code, but unfortunatlly its not as it seems

Comment: Please [edit] your question and use the code button on the toolbar to fix the formatting.

Comment: @Jester , I think it is now what you wanted, sorry if not I'm just new here so I don't know much how to use it

Comment: The service `int10/09` takes a repeat count in `cx`. Set that to one.

Comment: @Jester, can you please show me where to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that the service `int10/09` takes a repeat count in `cx`. For the first call you also forgot to zero `bh`. Furthermore for colored printing you likely want to print once and move the cursor. Using the character index and the known starting position (which isn't going to be the middle so you should calculate that using the string length) you could have something like:

```
is_vowel:
mov cx, 1 ; repeat count

mov al,bl
mov ah,09h
mov bh, 0
mov bl,[colors+di]
int 10h

inc si ; next char

mov dl, 30
add dx, si ; move cursor
mov dh, 12
mov bh, 0
mov ah, 2
int 10h

jmp output
```